# how can my customers view their purchased products history like an invoice in a specific page on Wordpress

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, order

how can my customers view their purchased products history like an invoice in a specific page on Wordpress. I need help please if someone can help me let me know. I have searched allot ways to solve this problem but still I cannot find a solution.

Comment: Please edit your question and give more information. Is it a plugin you are using like woocommerce? If not is it another plugin? If it is not a plugin then what is your database schema.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work. **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Consider explaining how you encountered the problem and your difficulties in solving it so far. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.